# Rails coding to link to next ranked supplier

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going round in circles and was hoping someone could help me...

My rails app has a supplier model (supplier.rb).

Each supplier has a show page (suppliers/show.html.haml). Each supplier is also ranked (i.e. ranking compared to the other suppliers). My aim is to have each suppliers/show.html.haml page display a link to the suppliers/show.html.haml page for the next rank down.

In supplier.rb:

```
def rank_for_category(category)
  Supplier.for_category(self.category).order_by_rating.index(self)
end

def next_rank_supplier
  Supplier.for_category(self.category).order_by_rating.index(self) + 1
end
```

In suppliers/show.html.haml:

```
%p View the #{@supplier.next_rank_as_text}th ranked #   {@supplier.category.name}    in the UK 
    = link_to 'next rank', supplier_path(@supplier.next_rank_supplier)
```

This isn't right. Maybe I need another function to get @supplier.next_rank_supplier right?

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the next element in the array.

```
def self.ordered_suppliers(category)
  for_category(category).order_by_rating
end

def rank
  Supplier.ordered_suppliers(self.category).index(self)
end

def next_rank_supplier
  Supplier.ordered_suppliers(self.category)[rank+1]
end
```

Comment: Also, consider memoizing `ordered_suppliers(category)` to improve performance. I'm not sure whether Rails will cache the same query in the model by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this method doesn't seem to return a supplier, it seems to return the ranking instead. You haven't shown your Supplier model, so I can't write the new method for you.

```
def next_rank_supplier
  Supplier.for_category(self.category).order_by_rating.index(self) + 1
end
```